# Adding a field with an automatic link in a content type from entity registration module

Tags: entities, users, navigation

I'm using Drupal to create a website which allows an "*employer_role*" user to create a "*Post Job*" content type that has a field type of registration from [entity registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/registration) module and inside that registration should contains information about an "*applicant_role*" user EX: Name, Job, Letter, and a automatic link generator where it will link it to the "*Applicant's*" resume content.

I'm quite new to Drupal and the only thing I can manage is a textbox where the applicant should mannually link his resume content path, which I also don't want the applicant's to put a link from another website.

Any suggestions to help me?

**Content type: "Post Job"**

> fields:
>
> Title : text
>
> company name: text
>
> job title : text
>
> body: text //job description
>
> register: registration // apply form

**registration form fields**

> Applicant Name: Text
>
> Applicant Job: Text
>
> letter: long text
>
> my profile/resume: auto link field which will direct to the
>   applicant's resume content

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I correctly understand the question, but it sounds to me that using the [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module might be the solution you are looking for. Here's a quote from the module's project page:

> Provides a field type that can reference arbitrary entities

If that's not what you're looking for, then consider editing your question to rephrase it somehow or to add more details to it.